# ReactJS JSON fetch with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to fetch JSON data and set it to the local state object.

```
this.setState = {employees:[]}
```

After fetching JSON and parsing it using

```
then(data => { this.setState({employees: data.employee}, ()=>{console.log(this.state.data)})})
```

After this piece of code, I faced an error message -

> Objects are not React child

How to set an array of objects fetched from JSON back into the local state empty array?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question needs some work. Please take a look at the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of the site, particularly this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should add relevant code to your question (formatted so that it's readable) as a [mcve]. In your case you should add the code for the component.

Comment: console.log(this.state.employees) try to console employees, why you are using data ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. For the above-posted code considering data.employees is an array then we can directly set data.employees itself in the this.setState({employee: data.employees}). Next we can access the state during render() using this.state.employee. No need of any other complication. Basically the solution to the above code problem is in the question itself. Hope this solution will be useful for developer community.

Thanks
Anup.P

Comment: Just to add to previous answer it is acceptable practice to write the fetch method above in the componentDidMount() method. Since it is asynchrounous request we are making. Thanks
Anup.P